# PostMessage to Current Active Process doesn't work for all process?

Tags: c#, winapi, process, desktop, user32

I have this code:

```
    const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    const int VK_DOWN = 0x28;
    const int VK_UP = 0x26;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern Int32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    private static Process GetProcessByHandle(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        try
        {
            uint processID;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processID);
            return Process.GetProcessById((int)processID);
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }

    public static Process GetActiveProcess()
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        return hwnd != null ? GetProcessByHandle(hwnd) : null;
    }

    public static void KeyUp()
    {
        PostMessage(GetActiveProcess().MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0);
    }

    public static void KeyDown()
    {
        PostMessage(GetActiveProcess().MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0);
    }
```

When i call the KeyUp/KeyDown it works only on some process, proccess like text editos, visual studio.

But doesn't work on Explorer.exe, iTunes.exe, Chrome.exe, Outlook.exe, FileZilla.exe and more..

I ran debug on console:

```
    while (true)
    {
        Process currentProcess = GetActiveProcess();
        if (currentProcess != null)
            Console.WriteLine(currentProcess.MainWindowTitle);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Here what I get from some applications:

```
ProjName - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)
?PostMessage to Current Active Proccess doesn't work for all proccess ? - StackOverFlow - Google Chrome?
FileZilla
Inbox - Outlook Data File - Microsoft Outlook
```

And on Explorer.exe i get empty line..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostMessage WM_KEYDOWN send multiply keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732633/postmessage-wm-keydown-send-multiply-keys)

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to read keyboard state in a Windows application, and responding to `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` is just one of them.  Applications can also use [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301.aspx) or [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293.aspx).  Applications can also respond to the [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646276.aspx), [WM_SYSKEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646286.aspx) and [WM_SYSKEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646287.aspx) messages.  Different applications will use different methods and if you are not simulating the one the application is looking for, it won't respond.

The problem you are having is slightly different than the one posed in the question that Raymond linked to, but the solution may be the same.  Namely using [SendInput](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput) instead of PostMessage

Comment: @Danpe Try sending `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` in addition to `WM_KEYDOWN`.  That may work for most applications.