# PostMessage WM_KEYDOWN send multiply keys?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, process, postmessage

I have this code:

```
    public static void Next()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("test");

        foreach (Process proc in processes)
            PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT, 0);
    }
```

This code sents the Right Arrow key, i want to sent ALT+CTRL+RIGHT i tried this:

```
    public static void Forward()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("test");

        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0);
            PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ALT, 0);
            PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT, 0);
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx), at least not reliably use [SendInput](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput) instead.

Comment: +1 I corrected your link. Obviously you meant it to point to one of Raymond's articles.

Comment: I tried understanding the example on SendInput without any success..
I need to send Keys to a non focused proccess that is runing on my PC, and not from my keyboard, from a diffrent event, like button click.

Comment: @Danpe, if the window isn't focused then SendInput wont' work.  Unfortunately they is no reliable way to simulate input on Windows.

Comment: There is no workaround for sending multiply keys using PostMessage ?

Comment: No there's no workaround - maybe UI Automation (if the client app supports it) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I have tried this so many times and it's hit or miss if it works.  What you want to do is try to use WM_SYSKEYDOWN instead of WM_KEYDOWN for "system" type keys.  This also means you have to use WM_SYSKEYUP.  Something like this might work:

```
PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0); 
PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_ALT, 0); 
PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT, 0); 
PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSKEYUP, VK_ALT, 0); 
PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSKEYUP, VK_CONTROL, 0);
```

Update:

I've it only to simulate key presses for single keys, it works great even for minimized applications :).  When using it as a combination key for "shift" states is where it's hit or miss.  The problem is most windows applications have a control and each control has it's on handle so sending a key to the window doesn't have the desired affect, you have to send ALT+S to the "Menu" handle to make a file save (in say Notepad), which also works.

Comment: Yeah, it's not going to. Use SendInput, or, even better, UI Automation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sometimes SendInput is not a valid solution if you're trying send keys to the non-active window.

Comment: You can't reliably fake input to a window unless it has input focus. You can reliably fake input to a window with input focus. So, I guess it all depends on whether or not you want something that works.