# Sendkeys sends no or multiple strings

Tags: c#, winforms, on-screen-keyboard

I made a keyboard in Windows.Forms with many Buttons and the content of them are the different characters of the Alphabet like a real keyboard.

Now the problem is when I am using the Keyboard in Windows 7 everything works perfectly. But when I use the Keyboard on the Touchscreen with Windows XP the keyboard writes multiple times the content of the button I just pressed or does not write anything inside of the textbox.

Here is some example code:

```
Button temp = sender as Button;
SendKeys.SendWait(temp.Text);
```

I have tried SendKeys.Flush and the

```
<appSettings>

<add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>
</appSettings>
```

inside of the app.config

which is the solution here [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28VS.90%29.aspx). But it didnt fix the Problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Now I found out the first letter always works perfectly. After that everything turns awful. Is there something else than SendKeys.Flush that I could try?

Comment: Ah, a lot of wasted effort. Windows provides an on-screen keyboard application already. All you need is `Process.Start("osk.exe")`. It works perfectly every time, no need for `SendKeys`.

Comment: Hi Cody Gray, thank you for your reply. The osk from windows xp is too small for my touchscreen. You can´t change the size of it.

Comment: Have you verified the button click events are occuring as expected on the touch device?

Comment: Yes I have. And if the click events were not correct the first letter which I press would not be correct.

Answer (score 2):

You're losing focus after the first letter... reset focus to the target before calling SendWait.

Answer (score -1):

The sendkeys function really is not the best of functions. 
Using the winApi and more specifically PostMessage will prove better.

Here is an example : [PostMessage WM_KEYDOWN send multiply keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732633/postmessage-wm-keydown-send-multiply-keys)

You will be working more directly with the message Queue, but it also means that you will have to handle extra things, such as layout/localization.