# Selenium WebDriver's Keys.chord() function does not work in Internet Explorer (9)

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, internet-explorer-9

I've been using keyboard shortcuts in Selenium to perform UI functions, and I've been using Keys.chord() to simulate simultaneous key presses. They work just fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer. In IE, it seems that each Key press is executed separately instead of together.

The following line works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE:
   `driver.findElement(By.id(id)).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ARROW_LEFT));`

I've also tried the Actions class in IE, to no avail:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(driver.findElement(By.id(id)), Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).perform();
```

If anyone can help me figure out a workaround for this (or if it should be working and that I'm just doing it wrong), it would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: your webdriver and  IE version?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a [similar issue earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479870/webdriver-key-commands-in-internet-explorer/14485192#14485192).
Couldnt come up with a selenium solution, so used this workaround instead:

```
import java.awt.Robot
...
Robot robot;
try { 
  robot = new Robot();          
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ARROW_LEFT);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ARROW_LEFT);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
}catch (AWTException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope that may help

Answer (score 0):

The current driver (2.45) with default options uses PostMessage which is unreliable for simulating modifier keys [1] [2]. If you set the IE option "RequireWindowFocus" to true then the driver will use SendInput instead which will work.

If using C#, you would create the driver like this:

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;

var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx
2. [PostMessage WM_KEYDOWN send multiply keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732633/postmessage-wm-keydown-send-multiply-keys)