# How to simulate SHORTCUT in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I don't want to use input simulator.
I wanna send messages to the Process in the background.
I can't find exact documentation of

```
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

My problem is I want to send shortcut, but it doesn't work when I Press CTRL 
-> then press buttons/release and release CTRL

```
static class Program
{
    const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Process [] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");

            foreach(Process proc in processes)
                PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostMessage WM\_KEYDOWN send multiply keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732633/postmessage-wm-keydown-send-multiply-keys)